# Batch file that can accept either a file or folder from the same input parameter

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I wrote a batch file that takes an input parameter. I originally wrote it to perform an operation on `%1` assuming that was a filename, but then converted it to expect `%1` is a folder and it iterates through all items in that folder and runs the operation on them using a for loop like so:

```
for %%f in (%1/*.mkv) do (
    ffmpeg -y -i "%%f" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -b:a 192k "e:\temp\%%~nxf"
)
```

But now I'm realizing that it'd be great to handle both folders and files on the same input parameter. I can't handle this using different input flags because I want to be able to run this script from a Right Click send-to menu.

How can I differentiate between a file and a folder from a single input parameter (and obviously perform different actions based on each)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-to-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script

Answer (score 1):

For arguments and for variables there is the modifier `~a` returning the attributes.
See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html
If the attributes contain the letter `d` it's a directory.

```
@Echo off
Echo %~a1|findstr "d" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo %1 is a directory
) || (
    echo %1 is a file
)
```